# How to use c sharp interface

Tags: c#

I have the following interface..It has a error which i had no idea why it happened. Basically for the interface part`string DoorDescription { get; private set; }` has to remove the `private set` to make it work

```
namespace test6
    {
        interface IHasExteriorDoor
        {
            string DoorDescription { get; private set; }
            string DoorLocation { get; set; }
        }
        class Room : IHasExteriorDoor
        {
            public Room(string disc, string loc)
            {
                DoorDescription = disc;
                DoorLocation = loc;
            }
            public string DoorDescription { get; private set; }
            public string DoorLocation { get; set; }
        }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Room a = new Room("A","B");
                a.DoorLocation = "alien";
                //a.DoorDescription = "mars";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MitchWheat   my question is both the interface part and class part use `get;private set;` why it didn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

> An interface can't contain constants, fields, operators, instance
>   constructors, destructors, or types. Interface members are
>   automatically public, and they can't include any access modifiers.
>   Members also can't be static.

Basically an interface is a [public contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576/non-public-members-for-c-sharp-interfaces).

You can set your property as read-only and then have [a private set in the class which implements it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767024/why-c-sharp-compiler-does-not-allows-private-property-setters-in-interfaces).

Answer (score 2):

An interface can't have any private methods.

Just remove the setter from the interface:

```
    interface IHasExteriorDoor
    {
        string DoorDescription { get; }
        string DoorLocation { get; set; }
    }
```

The class implementing it can still have a setter for the property, and as the setter is not defined in the interface, it can be private.