# How to make properties private despite interface?

Tags: typescript, oop

I have declared interface:

```
interface IMenu {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}
```

And class that realizes this interfaace:

```
class Menu implements IMenu {
    public name;
    public url;
}
```

Such as properties in interface are always public, it means class that realizes this interface must contain public properties. Is it possible to make them protected or private?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767024/why-c-sharp-compiler-does-not-allows-private-property-setters-in-interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Interface implementations must be public (some languages allow a bit of hiding, such as C# with explicit interface implementations but the implemented properties are still accessible from outside the class).

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IMenu {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}

class Menu implements IMenu {
    private _name: string;
    private _url: string;

    constructor() {
        _name = "name";
        _url = "url";
    }

    get name(){
        // your implementation to expose name
    }

    set name(value){
        // your implementation to set name         
    }
 }
```

You can define Getter and Setter for make Public variable from Interface Private/Protected on a class.